# Is clear:both; redundant?

Tags: css

Is it possible to mimic the behaviour of `clear: both;` using `clear: left;` or `clear: right;` in every possible situation? Thus, could it be considered as redundant?

Comment: Is the "redundant-code" tag useful ?

Comment: @dystroy:  No, it's redundant.  :-D

Answer (score 3):

If you write

```
someSelector {
 clear: left;
 clear: right;
}
```

only one of the two values is taken, this isn't at all equivalent to

```
someSelector {
 clear: both;
}
```

Reference on the `clear` parameter : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clear

Note : there may be a document where is defined if, in the first rule, the first (`left` ) or the last (`right`) value is applied but as having twice the same parameter in a rule is always a bug, I won't look for it.

Answer (score 2):

`clear: left`

The element is moved below the bottom outer edge of any left-floating boxes that resulted from elements earlier in the source document.

`clear: right`

The element is moved below the bottom outer edge of any right-floating boxes that resulted from elements earlier in the source document.

`clear: both`

The element is moved below all floating boxes of earlier elements in the source document.

[From http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/clear.htm](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/clear.htm)

The clear left&right are not used often, they have a niche case for when you need to clear only one side of floats.

Answer (score 0):

If you *know* that the preceding element is floated left then writing `clear: left` is sufficient. Similarly for `float: right`. However, if you don’t know to which side the preceding element is floated, then `clear: both` comes in handy since you cannot otherwise combine `clear: left` and `clear: right`.